# mpi4py: Communicating between spawned processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, mpi, mpi4py

I have one process running a program called t1.py which spawns 3 other processes, all of which run t2.py. I want to broadcast a value from the spawned process with a rank of 0 to the two other spawned processes. However, when bcast is called, the program blocks. Any idea why this happens? And how do I fix it?

t1.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=['t2.py'], maxprocs=3)
print 'hi'
```

t2.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_Parent()

print 'ho ', comm.Get_rank()
a = comm.bcast(comm.Get_rank(), root=0)
print a
```

output

```
hi
ho  2
ho  0
ho  1
```

Comment: I faintly remember that MPISpawn returns an Inter-Communicator in contrast to the Intra-Communicators that we are used to (or the other way round). You can however convert one type to the other. Please consult the MPI standard about this.

Comment: Do you ever call MPI_Finalize()? In all processes?

Comment: I guess the parent process must take part in the broadcast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the childs to talk to each other, you can use `MPI.COMM_WORLD`:

```
a = MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(), root=0)
```

By printing `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(), ' of  ',MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()`, you can check that the childs'`MPI.COMM_WORLD` is limited to the childs.

Now, let's investigate the reason why `comm.bcast(...)` failed if `comm` is obtained by `comm=MPI.Comm.Get_parent()`. Indeed, by looking at the size and ranks of this communicator, it seems very similar to `MPI.COMM_WORLD`. **But, on the contrary, `comm` is very different from `MPI.COMM_WORLD`: it is an [intercommunicator](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node111.htm)**. More precisely, it is the way a parent can talk to its childs. Collective communications can be used, but all processes, both the parent and its childs, must call the function. Please carrefully read the [MPI standards](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), in particular the sections 5.2.2 and 5.2.3 about Intercommunicator Collective Operations. Regarding `bcast()`, `MPI.ROOT` and `MPI.PROC_NULL` are used instead of the rank of the broadcaster `root` to specify the direction (parent to child of child to parent) and the sending process. Lastly, an intracommunicator can be defined on the base of an intercommunicator by using [`Merge()`](https://pythonhosted.org/mpi4py/apiref/mpi4py.MPI.Intercomm-class.html) (corresponding to [`MPI_Intercomm_merge()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Intercomm_merge.html)). In this intracommunicator, parents and childs do not belong to two different groups: they are processes characterized by their unique rank, as usual.

Here are the modified versions of t1.py and t2.py, where a `bcast()` for a intercommunicator is performed. Then the intercommunicator is `Merge()` and a `bcast()` on the resulting intracommunicator is called as usual.

t1.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=['t2.py'], maxprocs=3)

val=42
sub_comm.bcast(val, MPI.ROOT)

common_comm=sub_comm.Merge(False)
print 'parent in common_comm ', common_comm.Get_rank(), ' of  ',common_comm.Get_size()
#MPI_Intercomm_merge(parentcomm,1,&intracomm);

val=13
c=common_comm.bcast(val, root=0)
print "value from rank 0 in common_comm", c
```

t2.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()

print 'ho ', comm.Get_rank(), ' of  ',comm.Get_size(),' ', MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(), ' of  ',MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
a = MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(), root=0)
print "value from other child", a

print "comm.Is_inter", comm.Is_inter()
b = comm.bcast(comm.Get_rank(), root=0)
print "value from parent", b

common_comm=comm.Merge(True)
print "common_comm.Is_inter", common_comm.Is_inter()
print 'common_comm ', common_comm.Get_rank(), ' of  ',common_comm.Get_size()

c=common_comm.bcast(0, root=0)
print "value from rank 0 in common_comm", c
```